# Using Ionic framework and loading web app files from native faster

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app [Xpresso](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobigraph.xpresso&hl=en). Right now its made as a normal webApp hosted on a webView. The time taken for the transition from the splash screen (native part) to the first page of the web app is a lot. Also in slow networks it doesn't even open the web app and just shows a blank page.

Right now my biggest problem is solving the slow network problem, so if any solution specifically is there then I will heed to that first.

So, I went through this blog : [Handling 2G network](https://medium.com/myntra-engineering/leveraging-native-power-in-webview-105d248fe71#.lonra2cw8), where it talked about having web app files locally in the native and host from there unless a new version of the file is seen in the server, then use that and download in the native.

So, since this is not a very small change and the look and feel of my app is not that good, I am thinking of using Ionic framework.

So my question is, is there features in Ionic which helps us achieve what is mentioned in the blog very easily? As I believe this is a common performance problem for hybrid apps and most companies might be facing this,but am not able find a detailed solution, so if this thread is used for that then it will be of great help for a lot of people.